# What desktop collaboration software can share a single application?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver, remote-assistance

What collaboration software products supports sharing of a single application only?

Ideally outputting a standard VNC Client compatible data stream.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't use VNC, but the free [Microsoft SharedView](http://connect.microsoft.com/site94) is probably worth checking out. You can select which specific windows to share, or share the entire desktop. It also has built-in real-time chat between all users invited to the shared session. It only works for Windows though.

Answer (score 2):

UltraVNC has a setting called Single Window Sharing (Share only the Server Window Named:), but I've never tried it.  A few quick searches found a few people trying to get it to work without much success, but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

[Citrix can do that](http://community.citrix.com/display/ocb/2010/09/08/What's+cool+about+Secure+Application+Sharing+in+XenClient)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

For linux:

```
$ apt-cache show xpra

....

Description-en: tool to detach/reattach running X programs
 Xpra gives you the functionality of GNU Screen for X applications.
 .
 It allows the user to view remote X applications on their local machine, and
 disconnect and reconnect from the remote machine without losing the state of
 the running applications.
 .
 Unlike VNC, these applications are "rootless".  They appear as individual
 windows inside your window manager rather than being contained within a single
 window.
Homepage: http://xpra.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .. **Virtual Display Manager** (freeware)

This tool is specialized to single window sharing.
(and child window sharing)

You can work on the client with that single
window you want from the server **even if it is
not fully visible, covered or out of screen
on serverside**. You can work on a server
with others on different or the same windows
without disturbing the person who workes on
the server. Mouse clicks are simulated.

**Here:
http://ynea.futureware.at**

Answer (score 0):

TeamVierer 7 can do that, this is called "Single window mode". After installing TeamViewer, a titlebar button is added to every window. And yes, it's VNC compatible.

[image: TeamVierer 7 single window mode button]

Comment: Is TeamViewer really compatible with a regular VNC client?

Comment: No it is not. My bad. I forgot I'm running TeamWiever **AND** TightVNC so I actually connected to TightVNC when I was testing my advice.